# How does one function result in multiple functions?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, azure-functions

I'm currently working with Azure Functions and I just found this interface definition.

```
Assembly Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions, Version=1.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60

using System;

namespace Microsoft.Extensions.Logging
{
    public interface ILogger
    {
        IDisposable BeginScope<TState>(TState state);

        bool IsEnabled(LogLevel logLevel);

        void Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter);
    }
}
```

I am particular interested in `void Log<TState>`. This function has what looks like a generic, but seems to magically expand into 6 functions.

```
log.LogCritical("...");
log.LogDebug("...");
log.LogError("...");
log.LogInformation("...");
log.LogTrace("...");
log.LogWarning("...");
```

I receive the reference to log via the Azure Function defintion.

```
[FunctionName("WhoAmI")]
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequestMessage req, ILogger log)
{ ... }
```

The Microsoft [samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring#write-logs-in-c-functions) and [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger?view=aspnetcore-2.0) reflect this.

I'm guessing this is a C# or Visual Studio feature and not witchcraft, but which feature is it?

Comment: What's the type of the reference for `log` in your code?

Comment: @ZoharPeled, I receive it via the Azure Function as a method argument. Snippet added.

Comment: My only experience with cloud is rain... sorry... perhaps it is witchcraft after all :-)

Comment: see [LoggerExtensions Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.loggerextensions?view=aspnetcore-2.0) for that "magic"

Comment: @SirRufo so obvious... I guess it's time to go to sleep if I couldn't figure it out even without knowing anything about Azure...

Comment: @SirRufo, arrr, yes, pretty obvious really.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is C# feature called Extension Methods. These methods are defined in `LoggerExtensions` static class. Here is a sample signature:

```
public static void LogDebug (
    this ILogger logger, EventId eventId, string message, object[] args);
```

It's the keyword `this` which makes the call look like it's the member of interface.

[`LoggerExtensions` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.loggerextensions?view=aspnetcore-2.0).

[C# Extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods).

Credits to @SirRufo for giving the right hint in the comments. I just don't want to leave this question without the full answer :)